# Parse Batch Background Jobs to Bypass 15 Minute Limit

Tags: parse-platform

I am running a scheduled background job each night that pulls data from every one of our users and updates an element in the user data table for each user. This has an approximate time complexity of n where n is our total users. However, Parse only allows for 15 minute functions maximum.

I am trying to split our users into 5000 user-batches. That way, we can run the a function on each batch sequentially. Anyone know how to do this with Parse background jobs and cloud code?